# URLs with #: how does it work?

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

I've been recently studying MVC frameworks, particularly CodeIgniter, and I found out some of the advantages of working with them. One apparent pro is fixing URLs to make some more sense out of them.

I began to notice some of the URLs in websites today, and I can't really grasp some of them (what's the sense in using them, how does it benefit to the readability of the site, etc..)

For example, Jolicloud:

```
https://drive.jolicloud.com/#/setup
https://drive.jolicloud.com/#/services/dropbox/53e03563c389d0a00006a962/
https://drive.jolicloud.com/#/services/google-docs/53e03563c389d0a00006a961/
```

What's the benefit of using a hashtag isolated between '//' as part of the url?

Google Drive:

```
https://drive.google.com/?usp=chrome_app#shared-with-me
https://drive.google.com/?usp=chrome_app#my-drive
https://drive.google.com/?usp=chrome_app#starred
https://drive.google.com/?usp=chrome_app#recent
```

How does a URL like Google Drive implement these URLs? Is it using the MVC framework?

Answer (score 1):

you can change the setting of url in codeigniter, just open `config\config.php` and find this code

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

means the codeigniter only allow those character in url, if you want to add # do the code below

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-#';
```